# Validating against multiple JSON Schema

Tags: json

I've been looking online and the information available I've found has been a little confusing.

I've got a number of JSON schemas and need to check some JSON string against all of them. Rather than have to define each validation against a schema seperatly, I'd like to be able to define a parent schema, like I can in XML, which contains references to my schemas. I can then point to this parent schema and know that all my child schemas will be checked against and if my JSON string matches agaisnt one, will return as valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to mark your JSON object as valid if it matches _at least one of_ or _all of_ the child schemas?

Comment: The JSON object should be marked as valid if it matches at least one of the child schemas